# Laravel.Expected response code 250 but got code "553", with message "553 5.7.1 Sender address rejected: not owned by auth user. "

Tags: laravel, email, swiftmailer

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST= smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=noreply@mail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=noreply@colibri.az
MAIL_FROM_NAME=noreply@colibri.az

return (new MailMessage)
            ->from('noreply@mail.com', "No Reply")
```

Mail From address is same as userame but get error.
When i change address in ' new MailMessage->from('noreply@mail.com', "No Reply") ' to another any ,it works
What i must do ?

THANKS!!!

Comment: Solved by switching on  less secure apps.

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer** : `“Requested action not taken – Mailbox name invalid”`. That is, there’s an incorrect email address into the recipients line.

---

**Details Answer** : A **553** email error (*Mailbox name invalid*)  is normally related to **SMTP** authentication not being used. Most mail servers require that you authenticate with a valid user on that system, before you're allowed to relay a remote message out. However some mail administrators will also using the **553 error** if a user doesn’t exist or for various other reasons as well.

> **Fix** : Check all the addresses in the **TO**, **CC** and **BCC** field. There should be an error or a misspelling somewhere.

Comment: then why when i change 'from' address to another any it works ?

Comment: Its depend upon SMTP provider, may be your provider don't accept the request if both email address will be same.